# problem taking data from only one print function in a php page and passing to flash

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, variables

I'm trying to take a variable from a php page and send it to flash to then use in a link.

I'm having problems just selecting ONE variable from the print function, the code will help explain:

**PHP page**

```
<?
print"fbook=facebook";
print"tweet=twitter-test";
print"utube=youtube-test";
?>
```

**Flash code**

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest("../SC/FLA_tools-btn.php"));
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
fbook.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClickfbook);
tweet.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClicktweet);
youtube.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseClickyoutube);

function onLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
var data:URLVariables = new URLVariables(evt.target.data);
variables.fbook = data.fbook;
variables.twitter = data.tweet;
variables.utube = data.utube;
}

function mouseClicktweet(event:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.twitter.com/'+variables.twitter),"_Self");

}

function mouseClickfbook(event:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.facebook.com/'+variables.fbook),"_Self");

}

function mouseClickyoutube(event:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.youtube.com/'+variables.utube),"_Self");

}
```

It collects all the data fine but it does not print it out correctly, it prints out all the variables in the php in one link. For example:

If i click the facebook icon, i will be taken to `http://www.facebook.com/facebooktweet=twitter-testutube=youtube-test` This also happens with the other icons (Youtube and Twitter).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no separation between the variables you are printing,not even new line. you are printing in php fbook=facebooktweet=twitter-testutube=youtube-test   so maybe you intended to add new line? in that case add \n at the end of each line inside the quotes.

Comment: hey. Just tried adding the /n. Still does the same thing. Thanks

Comment: what I meant exactly is to separate the queries, as they were attached to each other. I wasn't sure what the separators should be . wasn't sure how flash was getting your php print exactly. so it seems the & worked for you like a normal url query.

Comment: @nav why are you returning data for facebook, youtube and twitter from your php file when you only need data for one of the 3? Its like going to a store to get a shirt and getting it in 3 different sizes, in the end your only going to need the one in your size.

Comment: hey guys, it's okay i have it working now. @Taurayi I working on a wordpress theme which will have Fbook Twitter and Youtube buttons on it in flash. I'm trying to make it as easy for the customer to setup as possible, so instead of them having to into the FLA file, they can just simply edit a PHP file. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: also, the users Fbook username and Twitter or Youtube user name could be different....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw data you are sending over the wire from PHP looks approximately like this:

```
fbook=facebook\n
tweet=twitter-test\n
utube=youtube-test\n
```

If you want to use it with the URLVariables class, you need to have the properties properly URL encoded. They should look like this:

```
fbook=facebook&tweet=twitter-test&utube=youtube-test
```

Modify your PHP script to looks like this:

```
<?
print"fbook=facebook&tweet=twitter-test&utube=youtube-test";
?>
```

Then you should be all set on the Flash side.

Answer (score 0):

How about approaching it differently? When you request the data from your php file from your flash application, you could specify what particular data you want. Here is an example of this:

Main.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="init(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.net.URLLoader;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
        import flash.net.URLVariables;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import spark.components.Button;

        public function init(e:FlexEvent):void
        {
            facebookButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
            twitterButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
            youtubeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

        }// end function

        private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var button:Button = e.target as Button;

            var requestString:String = "";

            switch(button)
            {
                case facebookButton: requestString = "facebook"; break;
                case twitterButton:  requestString = "twitter";  break;
                case youtubeButton:  requestString = "youtube";  break;

            }// end switch

            var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            urlVariables.request = requestString;

            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://projects.flashdevelop/stackoverflow/GetDataFromPHP/bin/php/getData.php");
            urlRequest.data = urlVariables;
            urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onUrlLoaderComplete);
            urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

        }// end function

        private function onUrlLoaderComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = e.target as URLLoader;
            var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(urlLoader.data);

            trace(urlVariables.response);

        }// end function

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Button id="facebookButton" width="100" height="100">Facebook</s:Button>
        <s:Button id="twitterButton" width="100" height="100">Twitter</s:Button>
        <s:Button id="youtubeButton"  width="100" height="100">Youtube</s:Button>
    </s:HGroup>

</s:Application>
```

getData.php:

```
<?php

    $response = "";

    if (!empty($_POST))
    {
        switch($_POST["request"])
        {
            case "facebook" : $response = "response=facebook-data"; break;
            case "twitter"  : $response = "response=twitter-data"; break;
            case "youtube"  : $response = "response=youtube-data"; break;
            default         : $response = "response=error"; break;

        }// end switch
    }
    else
    {
        $response = "response=error";

    }// end else

    print $response;

?>
```